# Iframe wont load in iexplore 8-11, wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

For some reason, my video on wordpress wont show up when I use iframe to view it. In I.E., it automatically loads the video into the windows media player versus playing through the iframe.

I am using a local mp4 for the video's. From what I can tell, there's no issues with my I-Frame code. Anyone got any idea's? I cant get it to play in the iframe!

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `<iframe>`'s like that. In the past it was a relatively more popular method, but extremely unreliable even back than.

What you should do instead is either encode your video's as `.flv`'s and use flash to play them, or encode them for the 'new' html5 `<video>`-tag for which no additional plugins are required. To get the best results with the new tag you should convert for 3 different codecs, but H.264 gets you quite far. This is how it ends up looking if you have converted multiple formats:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
</video>
```

And you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).